# dplyr: random sampling procedure for blocks of rows (multiple grouping variables and data columns)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data sets that have 1 to 70 columns of data with 1 to 5 columns of ID variables. I need to group by the ID variables and then randomly sample blocks of rows within an ID variable. The re-sampled data set needs to be the same length as the original data set.

Below is and example DATA set with the desired RESULT table. So, I need to group by `SITE` and `DATE` and then randomly sample the block of three rows (`aqu`, `n/a`, `terr`) associated with each `INDIV`. Please note how the `CATEGORY` order is retained within the RESULT table (e.g., `aqu`, `n/a`, `terr`).

I need to use `dplyr` because this random sampling procedure feeds data into a larger `for` loop that uses `dplyr` functions for various calculations….and as many of you know `dplyr` masks various functions in other packages. I apologize for copying and pasting raw tables into this question, but this was the easiest way to replicate the complexity of my data set. Thanks in advance.

DATA

```
SITE    DATE    INDIV   CATEGORY    BIOMASS LENGTH
GC  Oct A   aqu 0.0002  10
GC  Oct A   n/a 0   0
GC  Oct A   terr    0   0
GC  Oct B   aqu 0   0
GC  Oct B   n/a 0   0
GC  Oct B   terr    0   0
GC  Oct C   aqu 0.1875  20
GC  Oct C   n/a 0   0
GC  Oct C   terr    0.5424  30
GC  Aug D   aqu 7.4888  10
GC  Aug D   n/a 0   0
GC  Aug D   terr    100.9245    5
GC  Aug E   aqu 0.0001  1
GC  Aug E   n/a 0   0
GC  Aug E   terr    0   0
GC  Aug F   aqu 0   0
GC  Aug F   n/a 0   0
GC  Aug F   terr    20.593  10
NSVhi   Oct A   aqu 5.8713  5
NSVhi   Oct A   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Oct A   terr    13.8651 3
NSVhi   Oct B   aqu 17.2288 2
NSVhi   Oct B   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Oct B   terr    0   0
NSVhi   Oct C   aqu 22.7558 1
NSVhi   Oct C   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Oct C   terr    24.7843 6
NSVhi   Aug D   aqu 0   0
NSVhi   Aug D   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Aug D   terr    31.9222 7
NSVhi   Aug E   aqu 0.046   10
NSVhi   Aug E   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Aug E   terr    0   0
NSVhi   Aug F   aqu 2.1156  5
NSVhi   Aug F   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Aug F   terr    0   0
```

RESULT

```
SITE    DATE    INDIV   CATEGORY    BIOMASS LENGTH
GC  Oct C   aqu 0.1875  20
GC  Oct C   n/a 0   0
GC  Oct C   terr    0.5424  30
GC  Oct C   aqu 0.1875  20
GC  Oct C   n/a 0   0
GC  Oct C   terr    0.5424  30
GC  Oct A   aqu 0.0002  10
GC  Oct A   n/a 0   0
GC  Oct A   terr    0   0
GC  Aug D   aqu 7.4888  10
GC  Aug D   n/a 0   0
GC  Aug D   terr    100.9245    5
GC  Aug F   aqu 0   0
GC  Aug F   n/a 0   0
GC  Aug F   terr    20.593  10
GC  Aug D   aqu 7.4888  10
GC  Aug D   n/a 0   0
GC  Aug D   terr    100.9245    5
NSVhi   Oct B   aqu 17.2288 2
NSVhi   Oct B   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Oct B   terr    0   0
NSVhi   Oct C   aqu 22.7558 1
NSVhi   Oct C   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Oct C   terr    24.7843 6
NSVhi   Oct A   aqu 5.8713  5
NSVhi   Oct A   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Oct A   terr    13.8651 3
NSVhi   Aug D   aqu 0   0
NSVhi   Aug D   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Aug D   terr    31.9222 7
NSVhi   Aug D   aqu 0   0
NSVhi   Aug D   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Aug D   terr    31.9222 7
NSVhi   Aug D   aqu 0   0
NSVhi   Aug D   n/a 0   0
NSVhi   Aug D   terr    31.9222 7
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like what you might want....

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- group_by(DATA, SAMPLE, CATEGORY)
sample_df <- distinct(sample_n(dat, 3, replace = T))
```

But I think this makes more sense...

```
dat <- group_by(DATA, CATEGORY)
sample_df <- sample_n(dat, 3)
```

Then again, I don't know *exactly* what you want.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DATA, key = "SAMPLE")

set.seed(12030)
DATA[.(sample(unique(SAMPLE), rep = TRUE))]
#    SAMPLE CATEGORY BIOMASS
# 1:      B        1      10
# 2:      B        2      10
# 3:      B        3      10
# 4:      B        1      10
# 5:      B        2      10
# 6:      B        3      10
# 7:      A        1       1
# 8:      A        2       1
# 9:      A        3       1
```

If you're bootstrapping (I suspect you are) and planning on repeating this many times, it'll be more efficient to assign your randomization blocks first:

```
RB <- DATA[ , unique(SAMPLE)]
#repeat BB times
replicate(BB, DATA[.(sample(RB, rep = TRUE))])
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! However, after reading the responses, I realized the my original question did not reflect the complexity of my problem. Any solutions to the updated question are welcome. Take care.

Comment: @Vesuccio Instead of `RB <- DATA[ , unique(SAMPLE)]`, do `RB <- unique(DATA[ , .(SITE, DATE)])`, and instead of doing `DATE[.(sample(...))`, do `DATA[RB[sample(.N, rep = TRUE)], ..., on = c("SITE", "DATE")]`... I'm not 100% sure this will work but I don't like that you've flipped the question and nullified my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that Michael. I was not thinking.I should have just posted a new question. Thanks for you time.